# Is there a Python standard library class like collections.Counter() but with with lists as values?

Tags: python

The `collections.Counter()` class is pretty handy.  It only takes a few lines of code to implement something like that; but it's nice that it's in the standard libraries when you remember to use it.

I'm pretty embarrassed by how often I've re-written those three or four lines of code rather than using it, in fact.

But I often need to do something very similar ... accumulate values into keys within a dictionary.  However, the difference is that I want to accumulate the values as lists rather than merely counting them.  For example recently I wanted to deal with a boatload of LDAP DNs and I wanted to write something like this:

```
#!python
f = 'o=Foo,ou=bar,cn=this,dc=sub,dc=org,dc=somewhere,dc=not'
d = dict()
for i in f.split(','):
    k, v = i.split('=')
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = list()
    d[k].append(v)
```

(This was to allow me to easily generate a listing of all items returned from a search that's far less verbose than the DN specification: *Foo: bar: this@sub.org.somewhwere.not*, but that's more-or-less irrelevant to this question).

Is there some sort of "accumulator" class already in the standard libraries?  Something that's sort of like "update" or a counter but that appends values to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), like this

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in f.split(','):
    k, v = i.split('=')
    d[k].append(v)
```

But in this case, you can make use of [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), like this

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in f.split(','):
...     k, v = i.split('=')
...     d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
... 
>>> d
{'cn': ['this'], 'dc': ['sub', 'org', 'somewhere', 'not'], 'o': ['Foo'], 'ou': ['bar']}
```

Comment: Oh, yeah!  I keep forgetting about .setdefault() ... I remember .get() but forget about .setdefault().  Man!  I really need more sleep. :)

Answer (score 0):

Doh!

I thought of `collections.defaultdict(list)` before I posted this ... but perhaps I need to get more sleep.  I was just using it wrong and not realizing what I was seeing.

This works:

```
#!python
import collections
f = 'o=Foo,ou=bar,cn=this,dc=sub,dc=org,dc=somewhere,dc=not'
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in f.split(','):
    k, v = i.split('=')
    d[k].append(v)
```

Incidentally it's tempting, but probably egregiously bad form, to do that as a one-liner:

```
#!python
## Given the same f= and d=dict() from the original posting:
[d.setdefault(k,[]).append(v) for k,v in [i.split('=')  for i in f.split(',')]]
```

But, of course, this gratuitously returns a list of `None` objects for every item in `f.split(',')` which just seems wrong.  That's what I get for studying [clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure) in my spare time ... when I should be sleeping.